# Trigger an action when a specific price is applied to the product

Tags: triggers, hook, action, prestashop

I am new in prestashop (1.6) I want to trigger an email when a specific price is applied to a product. I don't know how to start. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic hook in your module:
actionObjectSpecificPriceAddAfter($params)
Object is pass in $params

Comment: Thanks very much your answer is what i was looking for. you save me